# How do DB transactions affect performance and throughput of MSSQL Server?

Tags: transactions, database-performance, throughput

Currently our server-side platform starts a DB transaction each time someone calls a web method and commits it after the web method returns. All web services are transactional, even those that don't update the database.

What is the performance impact of such decision? Will performance or DB throughput change significantly if I stop using transactions in web services, which do not update the database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will help especially due to reduction in caused blockings due to open transaction. But if the isolation level is such that it do not create blockings there will be no performance gain.
Also the performance issue if exist in mentioned scenario will not effect throughput or resource usage but it will cause high lock usages/waits and hence blockings.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

Make the transaction as long as you must to guarantee correctness, but not any longer.

For a Web API middle-tier, it is usually sensible to encapsulate entire Web API  method into a single transaction, as long as you make sure non-essential work (such as calling external services or processing HTTP request/response) is done outside of the transaction's duration.

### Slightly Longer Answer

In all relational DBMSes I know of, you cannot just "turn-off" transactions. If you don't start a transaction explicitly, it will be started for you implicitly and last for the duration of the SQL query.

So the choice is not whether to have a transaction, but how long it should be. In other words, should you have a separate transaction for each query, or encompass multiple queries (and how many)? This is specific to the logic you are trying to implement<sup>1</sup> and only you can make definitive decisions here.

There are costs associated with long transactions. For example, an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE query may place locks on the modified rows, which then may force some other queries to wait until the transaction ends<sup>2</sup>. Explicit locks (such as `FOR UPDATE` under Oracle or `WITH(XLOCK)` under SQL Server) will also be held to the end of the transaction, with similar effects. In cases like these, the sooner the transaction ends, the sooner the transactions it was blocking can continue with their work.

Also, you should always try to minimize non-essential work inside the duration of the transaction. For example:

- Avoid calling external services during the transaction - you don't want to block other transactions while waiting on a slow response (or worse: network timeout).<sup>3</sup>
- Parsing the HTTP request should be done before starting the transaction, and constructing the HTTP response after the transaction.

---

<sup>1</sup> E.g. what set of modifications should be atomic, or which read-only queries should see the same version of the data (if you are using a snapshot isolation level).

<sup>2</sup> In some cases writers can block readers, or block just writers, or block nothing at all. This is highly dependent on the current transaction isolation level, and the concrete DBMS implementation.

<sup>3</sup> In similar vein: avoid waiting for UI input during the transaction - you don't want to block other transactions while waiting on the user clicking a button (not really applicable to Web middle-tier, but I saw desktop applications doing this).